# Kendo MVC Bar Charts / Column chart CategoryAxis Fit day

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-chart

I'm facing a problem while using Kendo MVC Bar Charts / Column chart.

In the categoryaxis, I put date values. If I choose ".BaseUnit(ChartAxisBaseUnit.Days)" option in CategoryAxis, I get all date values of the month including the days where there is no value.

Is there any way to hide days where there is no value ?

[image: Chart]

Here is what I have;

```
<%= Html.Kendo().Chart<DaFyDaC.Models.KPIs.HistoryElecConsumpView>()
    .Name("kilovat")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Sort(sort => sort.Add(model => model.HEC_DATE).Ascending())
    )
    .Series(series =>
    {
        series.Column(model => model.HEC_POWER).Name("Power (kVA)");
        series.Column(model => model.HEC_CONSUMPTION).Name("Elec. Consump. (kVH)");
    })
    .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
        .Date()
        .Labels(l=>l.Template("#= kendo.toString(value, 'dd/MM/yyyy')#"))
        .Title("Month")
        .Categories(model => model.HEC_DATE)
        .Color("black")
        .BaseUnit(ChartAxisBaseUnit.Days)
        .AxisCrossingValue(0,40)
        .Labels(labels => labels.Rotation(-50))
        .MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(true))
    )
   .ValueAxis(axis => axis.Numeric("kVA")
       .Title("Power (kVA)")
        .Labels(labels => labels
            .Format("{0}")
        )
    )
%>
```

Here is my JSON data:

```
0: {DATA_CENTER: "CI1", CUSTOMER: "myCustomer", HEC_DATE: "02/02/2015", HEC_YEAR: 2015,…}
1: {DATA_CENTER: "CI1", CUSTOMER: "myCustomer", HEC_DATE: "02/03/2015", HEC_YEAR: 2015,…}
2: {DATA_CENTER: "CI1", CUSTOMER: "myCustomer", HEC_DATE: "01/04/2015", HEC_YEAR: 2015,…}
3: {DATA_CENTER: "CI1", CUSTOMER: "myCustomer", HEC_DATE: "30/04/2015", HEC_YEAR: 2015,…}
```

Comment: Hmm, I think using `BaseUnit(ChartAxisBaseUnit.Weeks)` is your only option.

Comment: no, ChartAxisBaseUnit.Weeks doesn't solve the problem. In one week, I can have more than 1 data, so it's not a good idea. but thanks anyway.

Comment: Can you please post your answer if you have already solved it. tnx

Comment: hey, please see my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I am not using Date() method inside CategoryAxis(). I consider that those date values are simply "string" values. I just format the date and display it. To have sorted date values (ascending order), I handle this in server side.

// Server side

```js
public ActionResult ElecConsumPerCustomer_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string customer, string datacenter, string year) {
  List < HistoryElecConsumpView > list = HistoryEcRepository.Instance.getHECDataPerCustomer(customer, datacenter);

  return Json(list.Where(ec => ec.HEC_DATE.Year.ToString() == year).OrderBy(ec => ec.HEC_DATE).ThenBy(ec => ec.EQUIPMENT).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

// client side

```js
<%= Html.Kendo().Chart < DaFyDaC.Models.KPIs.HistoryElecConsumpView > ()
  .Name("kilovat").Title(title => {
    title.Text("KiloVat Data").Font("16px Open Sans, sans-serif").Color("black");
    title.Position(ChartTitlePosition.Bottom);
  })
  .Legend(legend => legend.Position(ChartLegendPosition.Right).Font("Open Sans, sans-serif"))
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Sort(sort => sort.Add(model => model.HEC_DATE).Ascending()))
  .Series(series => {
    series.Column(model => model.HEC_POWER).Name("Power (kVA)").Color("#17c809").Axis("kVA").Labels(l => {
      l.Visible(true);
      l.Background("transparent");
    }); //.CategoryField("date");
    series.Column(model => model.HEC_CONSUMPTION).Name("Elec. Consump. (kVH)").Color("#147c0c").Axis("kVH").Labels(l => {
      l.Visible(true);
      l.Background("transparent");
    }); //.CategoryField("date");
  })
  .ChartArea(chartarea => {
    chartarea.Background("#F3F5F7");
  })
  .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
    .Labels(l => l.Template("#= kendo.toString(toDate(value), 'd/M/yy') #  (#= dataItem.EQUIPMENT #)  ").Font("Open Sans, sans-serif"))
    .Title("Month")
    .Categories(model => model.HEC_DATE)
    .Color("black")
    .AxisCrossingValue(0, 40)
    .Labels(labels => labels.Font("Open Sans, sans-serif").Rotation(-25))
    .MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(true))
  )
  .Theme("metro")
  .ValueAxis(axis => axis.Numeric("kVA").Title(t => t.Text("Power (kVA)").Font("16px Open Sans, sans-serif")).Labels(labels => labels.Font("Open Sans, sans-serif").Format("{0}")).Color("#17c809"))
  .ValueAxis(axis => axis.Numeric("kVH").Title(t => t.Text("Elec. Consump. (kVH)").Font("16px Open Sans, sans-serif")).Labels(labels => labels.Font("Open Sans, sans-serif").Format("{0}")).Color("#147c0c"))
  .Pdf(pdf => {
    pdf.Date(DateTime.Now);
  })
  .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip.Font("Open Sans, sans-serif").Visible(true).Format("{0:N2}")) %>
```